# MSVCR120D.dll After Conversion

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, deployment, visual-studio-2013

I have two Visual C++ apps. Both part of a DVR system. They share a single live555 library. On is a generic RTSP server. The other accesses cameras and downloads video clips using RTSP. Both compile and deploy fine in Visual Studio 2008. The one that downloads clips fails with missing msvcr120d.dll error. They are not compiled in debug. The both have pretty much the same compile/link options:

This works:

/GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy- /Zc:wchar_t /I".\" /I"SharedLibraries\mediaServer" /I"SharedLibraries\mediaServer\include" /I"SharedLibraries\LiveMedia" /I"SharedLibraries\LiveMedia\include" /I"SharedLibraries\Groupsock" /I"SharedLibraries\Groupsock\include" /I"SharedLibraries\BasicUsageEnvironment" /I"SharedLibraries\BasicUsageEnvironment\include" /I"SharedLibraries\UsageEnvironment" /I"SharedLibraries\UsageEnvironment\include" /I"SharedLibraries" /Zi /Gm /Od /Fd".\obj\Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MD /Fa".\obj\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo".\obj\Release\" /Fp".\obj\Release\VGRTSPServer.pch"

/OUT:"M:\VG CODE\Vg\V1\D1\Dvr\Output\Tracker Monitor\VGRTSPServer.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"M:\VG CODE\Vg\V1\D1\Dvr\Output\Tracker Monitor\VGRTSPServer.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "wsock32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"M:\VG CODE\Vg\V1\D1\Dvr\Output\Tracker Monitor\VGRTSPServer.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:".\obj\Release\VGRTSPServer.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

Doesn't work:

/GS /TP /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I".\" /I"SharedLibraries\mediaServer" /I"SharedLibraries\mediaServer\include" /I"SharedLibraries\LiveMedia" /I"SharedLibraries\LiveMedia\include" /I"SharedLibraries\Groupsock" /I"SharedLibraries\Groupsock\include" /I"SharedLibraries\BasicUsageEnvironment" /I"SharedLibraries\BasicUsageEnvironment\include" /I"SharedLibraries\UsageEnvironment" /I"SharedLibraries\UsageEnvironment\include" /I"SharedLibraries" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_CONSOLE" /fp:except- /errorReport:prompt /GF- /WX- /Zc:forScope /GR /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /openmp- /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\"

/OUT:"M:\VG CODE\Vg\V1\D1\Dvr\Output\Tracker Monitor\VGVideoBufferer.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"M:\VG CODE\Vg\V1\D1\Dvr\Output\Tracker Monitor\VGVideoBufferer.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "wsock32.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"M:\VG CODE\Vg\V1\D1\Dvr\Output\Tracker Monitor\VGVideoBufferer.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\VGVideoBufferer.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /CLRUNMANAGEDCODECHECK:NO /NOLOGO /ASSEMBLYDEBUG:DISABLE /TLBID:1

The only difference I can see is that the first one had more /DYNAMICBASE libraries, how would adding unnecessary libraries make a difference here?

Took a whack at it with depends, which says the predictable my app is dependent on msvcr120d.dll. It notes that all of c is involved along with some things I don't understand:

type_info::~type_info(void)
void * operator new(unsigned int)
void operator delete(void *)
void terminate(void)
_CRT_RTC_INITW
_CrtDbgReportW
_CrtSetCheckCount
_CxxThrowException
_XcptFilter
__CxxFrameHandler3
__crtSetUnhandledExceptionFilter
__crtTerminateProcess
__crtUnhandledException
__dllonexit
__getmainargs
__initenv
__iob_func
__set_app_type
__setusermatherr
_amsg_exit
_calloc_dbg
_cexit

(can't post an image. not enough rep)
I've been at this off and on for three days.

Comment: Libraries can be also linked from source code with `#pragma comment (lib, "libname")`, so you won't see those in linker options.

Comment: To try: Temporary rename MSVCR120D.LIB so the linker can't find it, this should cause a hard linker error.

Use the /verbose linker option(s) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx to try and track-down the cause.

Comment: No #pragmas, but a good thought. The bloody thing links fine w/o the library, but it's still demanding it on the test server??!! How can that be? (clever idea though)

Comment: Try scanning your source code for `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Hmmm . . . LoadLibrary("DAPassThru.dll"). But that's for the audio section, which isn't running.  Not this piece. It could be a problem though because it was compiled especially for us by Design Acoustics, by their tech.

Comment: SOLVED: I had configuration set to Release on the dropdown, but it wasn't the Active setting. (What good is a dropdown if you aren't going to look at it?) So some things were going out debug, which failed on the test system.